# Recommender System : ValueError at / could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I am trying to build a movie recommender web application using python and django. I am trying to use a command to take the movie's descriptions and create an information retrieval system to allow the user to find movies typing some relevant words. This tf-idf model is then saved in the Django cache together with the initial recommendation systems models (CF item-based and log-likelihood ratio).

The command to load data is

```
python manage.py load_data --input=plots.csv --nmaxwords=30000  --umatrixfile=umatrix.csv
```

Terminal Error

```
File "/home/anthra/server_movierecsys/books_recsys_app/management/commands/load_data.py", line 80, in handle
matr[0]=newrow
ValueError: could not convert string to float: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,
```

plot.csv screenshot

[image: plot.csv]
[image: umatrix.csv]

The code is as follows:

```
    matr = np.empty([1,ndims])
    titles = []
    cnt=0
    for m in xrange(nmovies):
        moviedata = MovieData()
        moviedata.title=tot_titles[m]
        moviedata.description=tot_textplots[m]
        moviedata.ndim= ndims
        moviedata.array=json.dumps(vec_tfidf[m].toarray()[0].tolist())
        moviedata.save()
        newrow = moviedata.array
        if cnt==0:
            matr[0]=newrow
        else:
            matr = np.vstack([matr, newrow])
        titles.append(moviedata.title)
        cnt+=1
```

moviedata.array output
[image: moviedata.array output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor change gave awesome result. Changed

```
moviedata.array=json.dumps(vec_tfidf[m].toarray()[0].tolist())"
```

to

```
moviedata.array=vec_tfidf[m].toarray()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

json.dumps generates a string to the newrow variable. And you're then trying to write the variable you serialized to a numpy array.

As I understand it, numpy arrays are confined to a declared type (implicit if you don't provide one explicitly), so when you have initialized the array with floats, the code tries to type-cast your string var newrow to a float value - which fails because you're not passing in a string representing a number but an iterable  of numbers.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you're serializing the data like that there. You could just do the other calls in that line, save the result to newrow, and only then json.dumps the variable.